# Inconsistent behaviour shuffling numpy arrays using TensorFlow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I encountered a strange behaviour while shuffling numpy arrays in Tensorflow (using Google Colab):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

seed = int(np.random.randint(0, 2 ** 16))
(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
train_x = train_x / 255.0 # this line
train_x = tf.random.shuffle(train_x, seed=seed)
train_y = tf.random.shuffle(train_y, seed=seed)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y))

for i in train_dataset.take(10):
    print(f"Label: {i[1].numpy()[0]}", end=', ')
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(i[0])
```

After shuffling train_x and train_y (both numpy arrays) this way, I visually confirmed that the relationship between the indexes were maintained i.e. seems each call to shuffle reset the rng and got the same permutation both times. However, when I comment out the normalization step (marked 'this line') the shuffling destroys the relationship between indexes.

I don't understand this behaviour and would like to find out why this happens. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on google colab your code *did not reproduce the same permutation whether the normalization line was included or not*.

What did produce the same permutation was setting the top level seed rather than the seed given to the function as a parameter like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

seed = 11030
tf.random.set_seed(seed)

(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
train_x = train_x / 255.0 # this line
train_x = tf.random.shuffle(train_x)
train_y = tf.random.shuffle(train_y)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y))

# ...visualize output or print results of arrays to confirm...
```